# Why in SwiftUI initializer call is different?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uicolor, tabview

I am starting to learn swiftUI and calling `init` of `Color` is very different.

I am setting `accentColor` of `TabView`.

Ideally it should look like this:

```
.accentColor(Color("Tab Selected"))
```

But it gives me compile time error:

[image]

What actually works is the below line:

```
.accentColor(.init("Tab Selected"))
```

Can anyone explain me why we have to write it this way?

Comment: `.accentColor(Color("Tab Selected"))` doesn't give any error

Comment: @jawadAli i have updated the question with a screenshot. Please check

Answer (score -1):

`accentColor` is a tint color you set for a view, and the view and all of it's subviews will adopt the same color you set.

`accentColor` is a View modifier.

You can set it like this:

```
VStack {
    Button(action: {}) {
        Text("My Button")
    }
}.accentColor(.red)
```

Comment: how it is related to the question ?